# Lottie.Forms - Load from EmbeddedResources

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, lottie

I've got a `AnimationView` defined in AirBnb's `Lottie` Framework which should load a file placed inside my Resource folder inside my Xamarin.Forms Project (the portable one)

```
        <forms:AnimationView
            x:Name="AnimationView"
            Animation="SharpLibrary.Forms.Assets.Images.WineGlass.json"
            Loop="True"
            AutoPlay="True"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

But it seems it cannot resolve the string in `Animation` property, so it will not display the animation. If I place the file into the Resource folder and say `Animation="WineGlass.json"` it works.

Is there a way to load it from EmbeddedResource, or is this not possible?

Comment: Did you try just use the animation name without the path and the extension? like `Animation="WineGlass"`

Comment: I tried it now, but still doesn't show anything

Comment: Animation Property loads the file from Platform Specific Asset not from your Portable one.
You can check out the implementation details here https://github.com/martijn00/LottieXamarin/blob/develop/Lottie.Forms/Platforms/Ios/AnimationViewRenderer.cs

Comment: Okay, and is there a way to make it load from portable ones?

Comment: Did you try to recreate the .json file in the correct directory of the specific project using Stream based on the shared project file?

Comment: @FilipePilettiPlucenio it only work when in platform resource folder, tried everything but it doesn't load from shared resource but there is one option, if I can generate NsUrl from the shared file then I can override it.

Answer (score 1):

It worked with me at
first you can put the json file at folder if you would or at the shared one

I put at folder renamed Image

```
Animation="Images.loading.json"
```

at the c# code put that

```
    animationView.AnimationSource = AnimationSource.EmbeddedResource;
```

Comment: This was added in newer version, anyways tha ks for the answer :)